# How can I connect my mongodb with the NODEjs app on Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud, monk, nosql

I have tried the below code for VCAP_SERVICES :

```
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
      var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
      if (env['mongodb-2.2']) {
        var mongo = env['mongodb-2.2'][0]['credentials'];
      }
    } else {
           var mongo = {
              "username" : "user1",
              "password" : "secret",
              "url" : "mongodb://user1:secret@localhost:27017/test"
     }
}

//With this as the connector
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var db= MongoClient.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("failed to connect to the database");
  } else {
    console.log("connected to database");
  }
```

but it keeps throwing " TypeError : Cannot read property "url" of underfined "

I have tried using monk as a connector giving :

```
var monk = require('monk');
 var db = monk(mongo.url);
```

This also throws the same error. I may be using the object mongo incorrectly.

Comment: Which version of mongo are you using is it 2.2  for sure ?

Comment: `var mongo` is out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like mongo.url is not defined, try restructing your code like below.

```
var mongo = {};

if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
    var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
    if (env['mongodb-2.2']) {
        mongo['url'] = env['mongodb-2.2'][0]['credentials']['uri'];
    }
    } else {
           var mongo = {
              "username" : "user1",
              "password" : "secret",
              "url" : "mongodb://user1:secret@localhost:27017/test"
     }
}

//With this as the connector
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var db = MongoClient.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db) {
if(err) {
    console.log("failed to connect to the database");
} else {
    console.log("connected to database");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my posts using mongoDB and Bluemix in my blog. In the code above mongo is not defined. You could move it up or remove the 'var'. This should make it accessible to other blocks of the code

http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/a-bluemix-recipe-with-mongodb-and-node-js/
http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/spicing-up-a-ibm-bluemix-cloud-app-with-mongodb-and-nodeexpress/

Regards
Ganesh

Comment: Thanks I forgot to bind mongodb as a service using cf. I followed the first blog that you mentioned and now I happy ever after with bluemix app :D

Comment: Also I had some issues with cf env variables as the structure is different now from the tutorial in bluemix. Definitely, viewing the env variable on console would definitely save lot of debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

app.js:

console.log('VCAP SERVICES: ' + JSON.stringify(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES, null, 4));

var mongoUrl;

if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {

var vcapServices = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);

for (var svcName in vcapServices) {

```
if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/)) {

  mongoUrl = vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.uri;

  mongoUrl = mongoUrl || vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.url;

  break;

}
```

}

}

else {

mongoUrl = "localhost:27017/SScheduler";

}

// Database

var mongo = require('mongoskin');

var db = mongo.db(mongoUrl, {native_parser:true});

//var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetest2", {native_parser:true});-->local

try like this,you don't need to mention any credential detail explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

two things are missing.

1. mongourl is not defined.

2.you don't need to mention mongodb version ,you can optimize the code like       below

```
console.log('VCAP SERVICES: ' + JSON.stringify(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES, null, 4));

var mongoUrl;

if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {

var vcapServices = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);

for (var svcName in vcapServices) {

if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/)) {  --->this part will take care of mongodb version

      mongoUrl = vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.uri;

      mongoUrl = mongoUrl || vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.url;

      break;

    }

  }

} else {

       mongoUrl = "localhost:28001/alpha";   

      }
```